# After performing a software update, my system is falling back to software rendering in low graphics mode

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics, gpu-driver

This question has been asked but not solved before on here.  I have an Ironlake laptop with a 520 M and integrated graphics.  It has been working fine for ~2 months now, but just today I performed a software update with the Software Updater application.  After rebooting, my system loaded the software rendering drivers instead of the Intel integrated graphics drivers and is using low graphics mode for unity.

Comment: I am not going into that dialog, I am running in software rendering low graphics mode, no pop up like that

Comment: @Zanna a 520M is an NVIDIA card I believe. It looks like OP tried installing Oibaf's drivers which caused an issue.

Comment: @Zacharee1 520M is my CPU model (Ironlake Intel), with integrated graphics, and now the problem is back for some reason, but I will try to figure it out myself this time.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix my problem by removing some ppas I had incorrectly added a few months ago:

```
ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/gallium-nine
ppa-purge ppa:commendsarnex/winedri3
```